# Should I wrap dispatch_group_leave in an @synchronized block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, grand-central-dispatch

Given the following code, is the `@synchronized` call un-required?

I assume that `dispatch_group_enter/leave` is atomic but it's not listed as thread safe here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_group_leave.3.html and I'm suddenly worried I've been messing up all this time.

```
// Imagine this is on its own queue already (possibly main, possibly not)
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
for(x in array){
  dispatch_group_enter(group);
  [x doSomethingAsync:^{
    // imagine x is part of a library which sometimes runs blocks on
    // a different queue.
    // surely dispatch_group_leave has its own internal synchronization?
    @synchronized(group){
      dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }
  }]
}
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to provide any additional synchronization when calling `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave`. GCD is, itself, providing concurrency and threading tools. If additional synchronization or barriers were required, my expectation would be that it would be called out explicitly in the docs, much like the requirement for `dispatch_once_t`s to have global/static storage is called out. Put differently, GCD *is* a threading library, so the expectation is that, unless otherwise stated, it's calls are expected to provide thread safety relative to each other.

This expectation is based on much personal experience and on Greg Parker making [a similar statement on a mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Dec/msg00140.html) a while back.

Comment: Yep I figured as much, like you said, it would be kinda dumb to have to thread-safe your threading library.

Comment: What about dispatch_group_create ?

Comment: Should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not spawning threads you should not worry.

In your example `dispatch_group_leave(group)` is called on the same thread.

Comment: Actually what got me thinking was because I was having the block called by a different thread (AFNetworking completion handlers are run on the main queue by default, while my code was running in its own queue). I have updated the question to be a bit more interesting?

Comment: I think that even if you `doSomethingAsync` in a different thread, the callback block is called on the main thread.

Comment: You can specify a different thread if you wanted/needed to, so its not impossible that it might happen, which is what made me wonder if the @synchronized was required there.